# Question about the connected sum of two smooth manifolds

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

I'm a little confused with the following two questions about connected sum:

(1) Is the covering space$\widehat{M\# N}$ of the connected sum of two smooth closed manifolds $M, N$ the connected sum $\widehat{M}\#\widehat{N}$ of covering spaces of the two smooth closed manifolds? If so, how do we prove this result?

(2) Is the connected sum $M\# N$ of a compact smooth manifold $M$ and a (probable noncompact) smooth manifold $N$ compact manifold?

Could you please give me some help with the details? I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: For the first part have you considered any examples? What if $M$ and $N$ are tori say?

Comment: The latter one is certainly false, look at the trivial counter example $M=\Bbb R^2$ and $N = S^2$.

Comment: What is **the** covering space? Do you mean the universal covering?

Comment: @PaulFrost Just certain cover space of a manifold,probably not universal cover.

Comment: Saying **the** covering space (without specifying one) is like saying *the* prime number  (without specifying one).